# SSRS Matrix - one value/row Adjacent?

Tags: sql-server, matrix, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I have a problem that I have been trying to solve... I Think it is fairly easy but I am new to SSRS. I have made a matrix showing the values of 2 different columns per country on one row. However I want to show only 1 value per row, that means that each country should get 2 rows each. 
I Think it has something to do with adjacent but I can't get it right :(

At the moment it looks like this:

> France   10   20

But I want it to look like this (don't the dashes...):

> France   10
>   France   ---    20

I think this should be possible to do without coding, I just can't find the right property/or Tablix function.

Is there anyone out there who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Change your data source so that it splits the rows.  So for example:

```
select Country, Value1
From CountryTable
Union All
Select Country, Value2
From CountryTable
```

You will have to consider your sorting to make sure that your rows are aligned how you need them.

Comment: Thank you but I have to use AdventureWorks2012 database and are not allowed to change it...

Comment: You don't have to change the database structure.  You can just modify your data-set query for the report.

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a weird requirement. But, setting the Row Grouping to Country and then Value should achieve this if I'm understanding your data structure properly.